# How can I achieve the blurred wallpaper view seen in Videos and other system apps?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

Is there any way I can use the wallpaper with a blurred view on top like many system apps?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIBlurEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView`. More [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial)

Comment: That's not what I mean. I'd like to use the actual wallpaper as if my app was a system app designed by Apple.